# Summing selective du sizes output

Tags: find, xargs, du

I am trying to find out how much space is consumed in total by files exceeding 50M in size. I am able to generate a list of file sizes with the following command:

```
find $PWD/soccer -maxdepth 50 -type f -iname "**" -size +50M |  xargs --delimiter '\n' --max-args=1 du -ha
```

But I don't know a clean way to sum them all up. Can `du` help me here, or is regex + `expr` the only straightforward way to achieve this?

```
52M /Videos/soccer/The making of Jari Litmanen part 1.mp4
55M /Videos/soccer/Van Gaal My philosophy makes me one of the best.mp4
68M /Videos/soccer/Zidane Brazil has always inspired me.mp4
```

The best I've come up with so far is this:

```
!! | xargs ruby -e "puts ARGV.map(&:to_i).inject(&:+)" | numfmt --from-unit=1000 --to=iec-i
```